# Reuse JAXB classes for similar schemas

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two similar schemas which have, for some elements, identical structure, but are defined under different namespaces. Is there any way to reuse the JAXB generated classes for the first schema when generating classes for the second schema? I know jaxb allows for binding customization, but I haven't been able to find out whether the same set of classes can be used **simultaneously** with two namespaces. More specifically:

Schema1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="ns1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ns1">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Document">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Root1" type="Root1Type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Root1Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child" type="ChildType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MndtId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element name="MndtReqId" type="Max35Text"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max35Text">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="ns2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ns2">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Document">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Root2" type="Root2Type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Root2Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child" type="ChildType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MndtId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element name="MndtReqId" type="Max35Text"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Max35Text">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

xjc will generate for the first schema:

```
ns1/ChildType.java
ns1/Document.java
ns1/ObjectFactory.java
ns1/Root1Type.java
ns1/package-info.java
```

and for the second:

```
ns2/ChildType.java
ns2/Document.java
ns2/ObjectFactory.java
ns2/Root2Type.java
ns2/package-info.java
```

What I would like to know is whether I can reuse ChildType generated for the first schema when generating classes for the second schema.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work for when you have multiple XML Schemas that only differ by the target namespace.

## Generating Your Java Model

Generate your model from one of the XML  Schemas (i.e. the one with target namespace `ns`.

## Handling of XML from Primary XML Schema

For any XML that corresponds directly to the XML Schema that you used to generate the Java model you can marshal/unmarshal it nornally

## Handling of XML from Secondary XML Schemas

### Unmarshalling

You can apply a SAX `XMLFilter` when unmarshalling to that when you are processing an XML document that corresponds to the schema with namespace `ns2` it appears as though it corresponds to the schema with namespace `ns1`.

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "ns1";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

Here is some sample code demonstrating how to apply the `XMLFilter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("ns1");

        // Create the XMLFilter
        XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter();

        // Set the parent XMLReader on the XMLFilter
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xr);

        // Set UnmarshallerHandler as ContentHandler on XMLFilter
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller
                .getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

        // Parse the XML
        InputSource xml = new InputSource("input.xml");
        filter.parse(xml);
        Object result = unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

}
```

### Marshalling

TBD