# How to use java objects from different schemas in a single function - Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JaXB to unmarshal an XML into JAVA object.
I have 7 different types of schemas but all of them have same structure(xml Structure). Just namespace is different in all of them(some business requirement hence it is like this).

I have to get the values from the java object and pass it .

I was wondering whether there is any way in Java(something like Generics) which will allow me to write a single function which will cater to all the different schema objects?

Please help.

Comment: Checkout the following for a different approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077971/reuse-jaxb-classes-for-similar-schemas/23085336#23085336